# Mongo (Node Js , Keystone ) field selection and slice cannot be used with distinct Error:

Tags: node.js, mongodb, distinct, limit, keystonejs

How do we integrate both distinct and selects the documents where the value of the field is not equal to the specified value.in a query in mongo using nodejs (keystone framework) ? or just basically in mongo. I am receiving an error which is field selection and slice cannot be used with distinct Error:. Any idea? or solution? I did try to use Syntax: {field: {$ne: value} } and that is the error. Also how can we include a limit when limit cannot be used with distinct Error: limit cannot be used with distinct.

## query

```
keystone.list('Customer').model.find({ customer_id: { $in: locals.data.customers } },  { vin: { $ne: vin } }).distinct('vin').limit(4) ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a query to distinct but not skip and limit

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#specify-query-with-distinct

Instead, you can use the aggregate pipeline as

```
db.customer.aggregate(
    { $match:{ customer_id: { $in: locals.data.customers } }},
    { $group:{_id:"$vin"}},
    { $skip: skip},
    { $limit: limit},
    { $group:{_id:null,vin:{$push:"$_id"}}}
);
```

Comment: he 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument